# Is there something similar to Mint.com for Canada?

Tags: canada, mint.com

[Mint.com](http://www.mint.com/) sounds like an interesting service, but it doesn't look like it works in Canada.  Is there an alternative for us?

Comment: Similar: http://www.basicallymoney.com/questions/947

Answer (score 4):

http://www.mint.com/canada/ They've released a Canadian version

Answer (score 2):

You could give [Wesabe](https://www.wesabe.com/login) a try. I have been using it for a while (I'm in Australia) and it seems to be promising. It still needs a bit of work though.